# Error with pip after upgrading : 'module' object has no attribute 'SSL_ST_INIT'

Tags: python, pip, pyopenssl

After upgrading pip, I try to do a 'pip freeze', but i've this error :

```
# pip install --upgrade pip
Collecting pip
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0f/74/ecd13431bcc456ed390b44c8a6e917c1820365cbebcb6a8974d1cd045ab4/pip-10.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.3MB)
    100% |################################| 1.3MB 737kB/s
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 9.0.1
    Uninstalling pip-9.0.1:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-9.0.1
Successfully installed pip-10.0.1

# pip freeze
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_internal/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from pip._internal import cmdoptions
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cmdoptions.py", line 16, in <module>
    from pip._internal.index import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_internal/index.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import html5lib, requests, six
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/__init__.py", line 86, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.urllib3.contrib import pyopenssl
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 46, in <module>
    import OpenSSL.SSL
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/OpenSSL/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import rand, crypto, SSL
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 105, in <module>
    SSL_ST_INIT = _lib.SSL_ST_INIT
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SSL_ST_INIT'
```

Reading some post here, I found various solutions, but it's not working.
So I try another things, like installing using easy_install :

```
# sudo python -m easy_install --upgrade pyOpenSSL
Searching for pyOpenSSL
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/pyOpenSSL/
Best match: pyOpenSSL 18.0.0
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9b/7c/ee600b2a9304d260d96044ab5c5e57aa489755b92bbeb4c0803f9504f480/pyOpenSSL-18.0.0.tar.gz#sha256=6488f1423b00f73b7ad5167885312bb0ce410d3312eb212393795b53c8caa580
Processing pyOpenSSL-18.0.0.tar.gz
Writing /tmp/easy_install-_qJ8_t/pyOpenSSL-18.0.0/setup.cfg
Running pyOpenSSL-18.0.0/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-_qJ8_t/pyOpenSSL-18.0.0/egg-dist-tmp-KM4cDC
warning: no previously-included files found matching 'leakcheck'
warning: no previously-included files found matching 'codecov.yml'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.py' found under directory 'leakcheck'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pem' found under directory 'leakcheck'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.cert' found under directory 'examples/simple'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pkey' found under directory 'examples/simple'
no previously-included directories found matching 'doc/_build'
no previously-included directories found matching '.travis'
no previously-included directories found matching '.mention-bot'
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
Adding pyOpenSSL 18.0.0 to easy-install.pth file

Installed /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyOpenSSL-18.0.0-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for pyOpenSSL
Searching for cryptography>=2.2.1
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/cryptography/
Best match: cryptography 2.2.2
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ec/b2/faa78c1ab928d2b2c634c8b41ff1181f0abdd9adf9193211bd606ffa57e2/cryptography-2.2.2.tar.gz#sha256=9fc295bf69130a342e7a19a39d7bbeb15c0bcaabc7382ec33ef3b2b7d18d2f63
Processing cryptography-2.2.2.tar.gz
Writing /tmp/easy_install-rHRU6X/cryptography-2.2.2/setup.cfg
Running cryptography-2.2.2/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-rHRU6X/cryptography-2.2.2/egg-dist-tmp-eABQpn
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/easy_install.py", line 5, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 2199, in main
    lambda: setup(
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 2185, in with_ei_usage
    return f()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 2202, in <lambda>
    distclass=DistributionWithoutHelpCommands, **kw
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 151, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 393, in run
    self.easy_install(spec, not self.no_deps)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 636, in easy_install
    return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 668, in install_item
    self.process_distribution(spec, dist, deps)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 716, in process_distribution
    [requirement], self.local_index, self.easy_install
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 631, in resolve
    dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, ws, installer)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 874, in best_match
    return self.obtain(req, installer)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 886, in obtain
    return installer(requirement)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 636, in easy_install
    return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 666, in install_item
    dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 856, in install_eggs
    return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1078, in build_and_install
    self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1063, in run_setup
    run_setup(setup_script, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 68, in run_setup
    DirectorySandbox(setup_dir).run(runner)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 114, in run
    return func()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 67, in runner
    _execfile(setup_script, ns)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 43, in _execfile
    exec(code, globals, locals)
  File "/tmp/easy_install-rHRU6X/cryptography-2.2.2/setup.py", line 28, in <module>
RuntimeError: cryptography requires setuptools 18.5 or newer, please upgrade to a newer version of setuptools
```

and, so, upgrading 'setuptools' :

```
# sudo python -m easy_install --upgrade setuptools
Searching for setuptools
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/setuptools/
Best match: setuptools 39.2.0
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1a/04/d6f1159feaccdfc508517dba1929eb93a2854de729fa68da9d5c6b48fa00/setuptools-39.2.0.zip#sha256=f7cddbb5f5c640311eb00eab6e849f7701fa70bf6a183fc8a2c33dd1d1672fb2
Processing setuptools-39.2.0.zip
Writing /tmp/easy_install-wH5_qA/setuptools-39.2.0/setup.cfg
Running setuptools-39.2.0/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-wH5_qA/setuptools-39.2.0/egg-dist-tmp-cpMLIT
/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'long_description_content_type'
  warnings.warn(msg)
/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'project_urls'
  warnings.warn(msg)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/easy_install.py", line 5, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 2199, in main
    lambda: setup(
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 2185, in with_ei_usage
    return f()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 2202, in <lambda>
    distclass=DistributionWithoutHelpCommands, **kw
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 151, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 393, in run
    self.easy_install(spec, not self.no_deps)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 636, in easy_install
    return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 666, in install_item
    dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 856, in install_eggs
    return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1078, in build_and_install
    self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1063, in run_setup
    run_setup(setup_script, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 68, in run_setup
    DirectorySandbox(setup_dir).run(runner)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 114, in run
    return func()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 67, in runner
    _execfile(setup_script, ns)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 43, in _execfile
    exec(code, globals, locals)
  File "/tmp/easy_install-wH5_qA/setuptools-39.2.0/setup.py", line 195, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 111, in setup
    _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 266, in __init__
    _Distribution.__init__(self,attrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 287, in __init__
    self.finalize_options()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 301, in finalize_options
    ep.load()(self, ep.name, value)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2195, in load
    raise ImportError("%r has no %r attribute" % (entry, attr))
ImportError: <module 'setuptools.dist' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.pyc'> has no 'check_specifier' attribute
```

And, the last try, using a specific version of pyOpenSSL :

```
# sudo pip install pyOpenSSL==16.2.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_internal/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from pip._internal import cmdoptions
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cmdoptions.py", line 16, in <module>
    from pip._internal.index import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_internal/index.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import html5lib, requests, six
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/__init__.py", line 86, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.urllib3.contrib import pyopenssl
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 46, in <module>
    import OpenSSL.SSL
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/OpenSSL/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import rand, crypto, SSL
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 105, in <module>
    SSL_ST_INIT = _lib.SSL_ST_INIT
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SSL_ST_INIT'
```

Another idea to resolve this please ? :)
Thanks a lot.
F.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is coming from `pyopenssl`. The first thing you can do is trying to remove and re-install `pyopenssl` :

```
apt-get --auto-remove --yes remove python-openssl
pip install pyOpenSSL
```

But it also could be a path problem.

Comment: Thanks, it's working. I do this : "apt-get --auto-remove --yes remove python-openssl". And "python -m pip install --user --upgrade cryptography" 'cause there's an error during installing : "python -m pip install pyOpenSSL --user". For now, it's working :)

Comment: The `pyopenssl` package may be installed via `pip` in which case the uninstall will be different - the key is to upgrade it to a recent version, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45188413/python-pip-install-is-failing-with-attributeerror-module-object-has-no-att) for more on how to do this, including uninstalling `pyopenssl` installed via `pip`.

Answer (score 3):

Upgrading the OS-provided `pip` is a well-known 'own goal' and should be avoided unless absolutely necessary.

First, you may need to re-install the OS package, to restore normal use of the 'pip' command.

If you must have a newer `pip`: try installing it from a self-contained installer, see here: `https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/` and not with the existing `pip`. Unless you must have it available for all users, run the install with '--user' option - and use the same option when installing packages with `pip` - that way you leave the OS-provided Python and pip things alone and don't overwrite them and can always return to them by deleting everything Python-related from `~/.local/`.

In all cases, after you recover from `pip` being stuck as you have it right now, try upgrading pyOpenSSL first (or `pip install`-ing it with `--user`).

Another helpful tip that I found somewhere on the Web: always use `python -m pip` instead of running `pip` directly, this avoids problems with `pip` picking up the wrong version or the pip module (or running the wrong `python` executable, if you've got more than one).

Comment: Thanks. I try to reinstall pip (using curl). And launch "python get-pip.py'. I've the same error : "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SSL_ST_INIT'" (using "--user" too)

Comment: I've no "~/.local/" folder

Comment: "~/.local/" gets created if you use the `--user` option.

Comment: I've the same error doing this : # python -m pip install --user --upgrade pyOpenSSL. The "~.local" gets **not** created :(