# How to connect to Snowflake using python snowflake connector from within Databricks in Python 3?

Tags: python, databricks, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, python-cryptography

When I try to attach the snowflake-sqlalchemy library to a Python 3 cluster in Databricks it breaks my python build and it gives me the following error when I install subsequent libraries:

> AttributeError: cffi library '_openssl' has no function, constant or
>   global variable named 'Cryptography_HAS_ED25519'

I have tried attaching the latest version of the Cryptography library to the cluster separately however this gave me the same issue. I think it might be related to the following links:

[connecting-to-snowflake-from-azure-databricks-notebook-message-openssl-has-no-function-constant-or-global-variable-named-cryptography](https://support.snowflake.net/s/question/0D50Z00008FNT3XSAX/connecting-to-snowflake-from-azure-databricks-notebook-message-openssl-has-no-function-constant-or-global-variable-named-cryptographyhassetecdhauto?t=1548339213324)

https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-python/issues/32

In the second link it mentions a workaround:

```
The workaround is:
Uninstall cryptography by running pip uninstall cryptography
Delete the directory .../site-packages/cryptography/ manually
Reinstall snowflake-connector-python

Looks like the directory structure of cryptography changed since 1.7.2.*
```

Is there any way to uninstall the pre-installed cryptography 1.5 python library within Databricks so that I can reinstall the latest version of cryptography (2.5) with the new directory structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an answer to my problem.

The issue is caused by the version of openssl in Databricks being too out of date for snowflake-sqlalchemy to work with it.

The solution is as follows:

1. Upgrade PIP

   %sh /databricks/python/bin/pip install --upgrade pip
2. Uninstall pyopenssl

   %sh /databricks/python/bin/pip uninstall pyopenssl -y
3. Install pyopenssl

   %sh /databricks/python/bin/pip install --upgrade pyopenssl
4. Install snowflake-sqlalchemy

   %sh /databricks/python/bin/pip install --upgrade snowflake-sqlalchemy

The answer to this question was helpful:
[Python AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SSL_ST_INIT'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43267157/python-attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-ssl-st-init)

I have created an init file using the following code:

```
dbutils.fs.mkdirs("dbfs:/databricks/init/")

dbutils.fs.put("dbfs:/databricks/init/sf-initiation.sh" ,"""
#!/bin/bash
/databricks/python/bin/pip install --upgrade pip
/databricks/python/bin/pip uninstall pyopenssl -y
/databricks/python/bin/pip install --upgrade pyopenssl
/databricks/python/bin/pip install --upgrade snowflake-sqlalchemy
""", True)
```

The last command in the file updates all outdated packages as in:
[Upgrading all packages with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720014/upgrading-all-packages-with-pip#3452888)

Answer (score 1):

Out of date libraries:

```
%sh sudo apt-get install python3-pip -y
```

Followed by:

```
%sh pip3 install --upgrade snowflake-connector-python
```

See https://datathirst.net/blog/2019/1/11/databricks-amp-snowflake-python-errors for more detail.

Comment: This solution might work for the snowflake-connector-python but not for snowflake-sqlalchemy. I have found a different solution to my problem and have posted the answer below.