# no pip command works on ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip

i try to use PIP command on ubuntu terminal but i has problems in this command because of OpenSSl library, all solutions i found tell i must install it but installing it need PIP again so still in loop, i tried install it without PIP but same error i see.

```
 from OpenSSL import rand, crypto, SSL
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 112, in <module>
    SSL_ST_INIT = _lib.SSL_ST_INIT
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SSL_ST_INIT'
```

Comment: try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43267157/python-attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-ssl-st-init

Comment: this need pip command, but pip do not work and return the above error.

Comment: try with `python -m easy_install` for that solution

Comment: have you tried to install pip ?

Comment: yes but i think problem looks in python bath, because when i use which command i see 

for pip:
/usr/local/bin/pip

for python:
/usr/bin/python

Comment: no i tried this solution before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/OpenSSL
sudo pip install pyopenssl
```

Comment: pip do not work how i cant install with it

Comment: oh thanks i tried it solved my problem after deleting OpenSSL