# Error installing Django package django-tenants

Tags: django

When attempting to install django-tenants via "pipenv install django-tenants" I get the following error:

```
_lib.ERR_load_RAND_strings()
AttributeError: module 'lib' has no attribute 'ERR_load_RAND_strings'
```

This is with Django version 3.1.13 and python is 3.9.2.

Any ideas about how to fix this?

Comment: This seems to be related to some problem with my virtual environment. I am getting a similar error when I attempt to install other packages.

Comment: This is answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43267157/python-attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-ssl-st-init/43267158 namely `pip uninstall pyopenssl` and `pip install pyopenssl` fixes it (without getting the same error from `pip upgrade` or `easy_install`)